# SWI-prolog memory to upload a file

Tags: http, swi-prolog

I have a problem, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/FileUpload.html), but when I upload a file, it remains in memory and is never released.

I use `swi-prolog 6.6.6` and I tried with `swi-prolog 7.1.36`

How I can do to free up memory?

Comment: Did you fully copy the code, or did you make small modifications? Note that some runtime environments do not release memory, but simply reuse it for other tasks. It results in less questions to the operating system for more or less memory.

Comment: On the top of the page you linked it also says "NOTE This example requires SWI-Prolog 7.2 or later."